# Is MySQL ping command in C++ blocking

Tags: mysql

just want to know if the mysql_ping command in c++ (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-ping.html) is blocking? As in if the internet connection is down, the program will stop at this command indefinitely until internet connection resumes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set mysql\_ping timeout with MySQL++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079788/how-to-set-mysql-ping-timeout-with-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This function is blocking. Because it return the result in return value, not callback / event notification / Future.

Comment: Will there be a way to have a non blocking check to the database?

Comment: No way with the offical client library. You can only wrap this API with your own faked non-blocking API(which still block a thread).